# how to redirect to servlet with values

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

i want to redirect from login page to home page(.jsp) and i want to display the value of login in the home page, i used window.location.replace but the value in home page is "null".in first time i send the data to servlet and the servlet redirect to the home page.

login.html

```
<form>
      <p><input type="text" id="login" ></p>  
     <p> <input type="button" value="LOGIN" id="log"  ></p>  
    </form>
```

login.js

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
$("#log").click(function (){
var log = $("#login").val();    

   $.post("Test",{log:log},function(){

 }).success(function (){

     window.location.replace("Test?log="+log) ;

  });
```

servlet:Test.java

```
String l =request.getParameter("log");

request.setAttribute("l", l);
```

getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp").forward(request,response);

home.jsp

```
<body>
<% out.println(request.getAttribute("l")) ; %>
</body>
```

thanks.

Comment: add the text into session.. its also a way to send data on other pages.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You could have simply submitted the login.html to home.jsp in order to get the login value.

Comment: i want to use the servlet as controller,all html page send request to the servlet and the servlet redirect to different pages

Answer (score 0):

you must use the attribute `name` of the html tag `input` to get the value of the `input` on your servlet

Comment: <input name="log" type="button" value="LOGIN" id="log">

Comment: sorry , the problem isin't there,i want to redirect to the servlet and from the servlet to the home page, i want to display the value of input text in the home page.jsp

Comment: You try to display in console what you get in your servlet? If you don't get the parameter with his name it will not work

Answer (score 0):

1. When you post form data from ajax request to Servlet, the servlet send response with content from home.jsp but, it cannot redirect the browser to home.jsp as it is the ajax request. So you need to manually (using window.location.href attribute) redirect the browser to home.jsp.
2. Setting request attributes only works per request basis. In your case it will work for first time when sending response to your ajax request, not when redirecting to home.jsp.So use session level attrbutes.

I suggest following code changes:

login.js

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
$("#log").click(function (){
var log = $("#login").val();    

   $.post("Test",{log:log},function(){

 }).success(function (){

     window.location.href="home.jsp" ;

  });
```

servlet:Test.java

```
String l =request.getParameter("log");

request.getSession().setAttribute("l", l);
```

home.jsp

```
<body>
<%=session.getAttribute("l") %>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for you suggestion, but i have "null" in the home page

Comment: @mass_develop  Also please post the login html form page.

Comment: thanks vijay, i tried your updated code but same result "null", also i don't understand what do you mean about "post the login html form page"

Comment: @mass_develop I mean, post the code of login page which uses the login.js code.

Comment: <body>
        <form>
          <p><input type="text"  id="login" ></p>
         <p> <input type="button" value="LOGIN"  id="log"  ></p>  
        </form>